# Создание и удаление временных файлов

Tags: vim

Интегрировал в `vim` такую тулу как `luacheck` для проверки кода на `lua` с помощью простейшей функции:

```
function! LuaCheck()
  let errors=system("luacheck ".expand("%"))
  cexpr errors
  cwindow 5
endfunction
autocmd FileType lua nnoremap <buffer> <c-f> :call LuaCheck()<cr>
autocmd FileType lua set efm=%f:%l:%c:\ %m
```

Однака, как можно увидеть по `expand("%")` я использую текущий файл для валидации, а не содержимое буфера, в результате чего если есть какие-то несохраненные изменения в буфере, то они не будут учтены. Это из-за того, что `luacheck` не имеет интерактивного режима. Это можно исправить просто скопировав содержимое буфера во временный файл, но я не нашел как средствами `vim` создать и удалить такой временный файл.

PS. Понятно, что это можно сделать и средствами `OS`, но это будет платформо-зависимое решение.

Comment: Так почему бы не записать во временный файл (типа `:write %.temp.lua`) и прогонять тесты на нём?

Comment: @AlexeyTen так вопрос как раз таки о том, как создавать временные файлы, а не что делать

Comment: Не понял. Что бы создать временный файл нужно просто сохранить текущий буфер под другим именем.

Comment: @AlexeyTen ну так в этом и был вопрос: я не знал как сохранить текущий буфер под другим именем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно как-то так сделать:

```
let l:tmpfname=tempname() . '.lua'
execute 'write' fnameescape(l:tmpfname)
let errors=system("luacheck " . l:tmpfname)
call delete(l:tmpfname)
```

Всё это с поправкой по необходимости или вкусу на расположение файла и прочее.
Также было бы разумно передавать `LuaCheck()` файл в качестве аргумента.

---

Но ИМХО практичнее было бы оставить (примерно) как есть, а запускать линтер при записи в файл:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.lua call LuaCheck()
```

---

Также уже готовая поддержка `luacheck` есть в [syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic). Если создание собственного костыля не является самоцелью, то я бы порекомендовал этот плагин.